# Is FileObserver atomic (in android)?

Tags: java, android

It doesn't seem to be stated in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver); is `FileObserver` atomic in android?

Comment: What do you mean by atomic in this context?

Comment: Two or more file observers watch a file; some may have to update it while others are only readers. Can there be a case where readers get an incompletely written file (that writers are still writing to)?

Comment: I see. Since the documentation states that the handlers run "on a special FileObserver thread", I guess that means that no two observers will have their `onEvent` running concurrently. Note that this doesn't mean that observers could observe incomplete writes, because the writes could come from anywhere.